# Vertical scroll bar appearing momentarily on page load

Tags: html, css

I have a page that, when loading, displays a vertical scroll bar that disappears once the page has finished loading. Is there any way to trace this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Overflow:hidden on your maindiv.

Means just make body style overflow-y:hidden
and on hover on body just change the style to overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: If I do that, then when I need the scrollbar it doesn't appear. I have a single page app.

Comment: Turn your intirw page invisible in the top of your CSS file and in JS, after the page loads, turn it back on. As it is, your page takes enought time loading to allow the user to see all the page being prepared. You can also consider improving your app loading speed, one of most common mistakes is the usage of images without optimizing them before using them.